# NSImage at app start

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsimage, nsimageview

I have an image view object.  I can get it to load images when a buttun is pressed but I want to know if there is a way to get it to load at the start of the app.

The code im using is

```
NSURL *lURL = nil;
NSData *lData = nil;
NSImage *lImage = nil;
lData = [lURL resourceDataUsingCache:YES];
lImage = [[NSImage allocWithZone:[self zone]] initWithData:lData];
lURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"urltoimage"];
[imageView setImage:lImage];
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` method which is called exactly once when the controller is first loaded into the memory.